# add_custom_command() not compiling my project glib resources

Tags: cmake

GTK project has the ability to bundle resources as library with the executable target, and it is done with the help of `glib-compile-resources` program.

I have to compile my resources first before building the target project but CMake's `add_custom_command()` is not doing anything at all in this sample dummy project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(dummy)

find_program(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES NAMES glib-compile-resources REQUIRED)
mark_as_advanced(GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES)

set(GRESOURCE test.gresource)
set(GRESOURCE_XML test.gresource.xml)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${GRESOURCE}
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMAND ${GLIB_COMPILE_RESOURCES}
    ARGS
        --target=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${GRESOURCE}
        ${GRESOURCE_XML}
    VERBATIM
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${GRESOURCE_XML}
    DEPENDS
        hello.txt
        world.txt
)
```

My expected output is the generated **test.gresource** from test.gresource.xml file, however, I don't find that file in the out-of-source build directory.

Comment: I did binary_dir too, didn't help. Also, I'm really confused because I don't really know if working dir is supposed to be the output directory or input directory.

Comment: CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR is correct. It's for finding the input file for that custom command :)